# What is the point of the usb port at the back of some routers?

Tags: router, wireless-router

I noticed that some routers have a usb port (at least one) at the back.

What is it used for?

Is it possible to plug a usb flash drive into the router?

Comment: It might be a good idea to take a look at what the manual says - capabilities and compatibility may vary between routers.

Comment: Are you trying to say I don't know anything!

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should take a look at the manual to know exactly what its for. However if I did think I didn't know anything, the manual is the good start. Yes, I'm telling you to RTFM, but only cause you'd find a *detailed*, **correct** answer there.

Comment: Ohhhhh I don't have the router therefore I don't have the manual!

Comment: Manuals for most routers can be located by entering a search term like [Netgear AC5300 PDF Manual](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Netgear+AC5300+PDF+Manual) into a search engine.

Comment: @HenryWHHack Your question says "Can I plug a usb flash drive into **my** router?". You comment says "I don't have the router". Which is correct? Are you trying to confuse us?

Comment: I only ask one question and I am blocked for four days what!

Comment: Can I use any mordem with any router?

Comment: @Henry: maybe some people didn't understood your question as you intended, but it shouldn't be the reason for you to be rude and offensive. Editing your question after having a look in the [help center](http://superuser.com/help), especially in sections "how to ask" and "our model" might help to improve your post.

Comment: Downvoted -  open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site.
Also the OP tone is not very civil.

Comment: The looks is different from the sound.

Comment: A single question does not result in a question ban which means you have questions in the past that have not been well recieved.  You were even warned before you submitted this question of that fact.

Answer (score 3):

These are usually for sharing a USB drive among your network. The functionality varies from router to router, but you should find in the settings or manual information on the use of the USB port.

Some routers allow for [USB printer connectivity](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/install-usb-printer-wireless-router-52835.html) also, but you will need to check your manual for exactly what is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most routers have a file-sharing service for usb-sticks.
I've also seen routers capable of turning a usb-printer into a network printer, also very useful.